# administering new website - Found really tiny keywords inside page

Tags: keywords

I'm administering this new website.

The previous web admin included a large amount of tiny keywords on top of some of its pages.

I've removed them already.

I need to know if I have to rest the domain with google webmaster or will google notice the change and take action?

thanks in advance.

edit: They are not meta keyword. They are literally text so small that it looks like a fine line of gibberish on the page itself. This clearly violates google guidelines. My point was more: Do I need to tell google that we are not bad pupils anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Google will notice the change eventually. However you can request reconsideration:

> If your site isn't appearing in Google
>   search results, or it's performing
>   more poorly than it once did (and you
>   believe that it does not violate our
>   Webmaster Guidelines), you can ask
>   Google to reconsider your site.
>
> [Request reconsideration of your site.](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration)

While that doesn't quite apply they also say:

> In addition, if you recently purchased
>   a domain that you think may have
>   violated our guidelines before you
>   owned it, you can use the
>   reconsideration request form to let us
>   know that you recently acquired the
>   site and that it now adheres to the
>   guidelines.

from https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843&hl=en_GB

Answer (score 0):

You can get Google to change the cache version of your site extra quick if you submit a sitemap with Google Webmaster tools and 301 redirect 'old' URLs to 'new' URLs.

In your .htaccess you can put a rewrite rule in to migrate your site 'slightly', i.e. put a new /path/ in the front of it.

You will need to download the URLs Google has on you, put them into a big spreadsheet and spend time submitting it, however, the results can be truly beneficial - you will only have the URLs you want to have on Google and they will be freshly indexed to your new content.

As for meta keywords - Google dropped using them back in the days when people thought it was a good idea to use them for spammy purposes. Instead of completely dropping them put some RDFa or other micro-formats on your page to get new, improved SEO 2.0 semantic-web search excellence.